# find string and check for second

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

Every file have first line that start with `a 1 b` followed by unknown_string
and remaining lines starting with `c` followed by unknown_string

I want to check the string AFTER the `a 1 b` is present in any of the next lines (compare unknown_string on first line to unknown_string on the next lines). If there is a match - to print `YES` if not `NO`, but to keep the path and filename?

Inputs

```
loken@lokenU:/home$ cat /home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test1.cfg
 a 1 b Test_1
c Test_1
loken@lokenU:/home$ cat /home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test2.cfg
 a 1 b Test_2
c Test_2
loken@lokenU:/home$ cat /home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test3.cfg
 a 1 b Test_3
c Test_2
c Test_4
loken@lokenU:/home$ cat /home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test4.cfg
 a 1 b Test_4
c Test_2
c Test_3
```

Output should be similar:

```
/home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test1.cfg: Yes
/home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test2.cfg: Yes
/home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test3.cfg: NO
/home/loken/Documents/bash-test/test4.cfg: NO
```

Comment: Feedback: down votes you got may be because: (1) the question used to be a cross-site duplicate (this issue is no more but downvoters may not be aware); (2) the question doesn't show any research effort. Please note Super User is not a script writing service. Requests like "I want something that takes input A and gives output B" may get some answers but they are not considered good questions. See [ask]. Your future similar questions should introduce your solution attempts. They may be partial, flawed or even completely wrong, just let us know you're not sitting tight while others work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Sorry for trouble (delete other post). Before  asking my question, I searched for the site's search engine as well as Google mote then 3-4 hours. Then I made a profile here and asked. This is perhaps my first or second post I will try to keep the rules in the future. I know very well that no one owes me, and I can ask what I want and expect a answer, but here I got into trouble after a half-day wonder - and that's the idea of ​​this society to help, right :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne 'if ($. == 1) { ($s) = /a 1 b (.*)/; $f = 0; }
           else { -1 != index $_, $s and $f = 1; }
           if (eof) { print $ARGV, "\t", $f ? "YES" : "NO"; $. = 0}
    ' *.cfg
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` adds newlines to prints
- `$.` contains the input line number. On the first line, the string is stored in $s by matching with a capture group, and $f ("found") is set to zero (false).
- Otherwise (not first line), $f is set to true (1) if the string is found
- At an end of file, the line count is reset, and the filename is printed with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) with a *for loop* :

```
for file in test*.cfg; do 
    awk '
        NR==1 && $1 == "a" && $2 == "1" && $3 == "b"{pattern=$4;next}
        (pattern !~ $2) {count++}
        END{print (count) ? FILENAME " NOK" : FILENAME " OK"}    
    ' "$file"
done
```

### Output :

```
test1.cfg OK
test2.cfg OK
test3.cfg NOK
test4.cfg NOK
```